# Can't catch enqueued style

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-style

I'am stuck in catching enqueued style. I try to optimize website for PageSpeed. Site use plugin `WPBakery Visual Composer` as `WYSIWYG editor`. Every block supports Google Fonts, which added with `wp_enqueue_style`, but without `add_action`, just call `wp_enqueue_style`. In my `functions.php`, when I try to dequeue this style, to load this font with JS, I don't see this style in list of enqueued styles. I call this code, but I don't see the id in the list

```
function inspect_styles() {
        global $wp_styles;
        print_r($wp_styles->queue);
        print_r($wp_styles->registered);
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'inspect_styles' );
```

The id of style generated automaticaly - maybe this is the reason?

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'vc_google_fonts_' . vc_build_safe_css_class( $google_fonts_data['values']['font_family'] ), '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' . $google_fonts_data['values']['font_family'] . $subsets );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good place to start, definitely you will find your answer - https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=524319

Comment: Please don't just add a link, add your own answer. Also, that link has nothing to do with the question.